# Matplotlib - Value Error - DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I'm trying to plot a shape onto a matplotlib generated graph but errors are being thrown. Here is my full function...

```
 def graphData(self, stock):
    stock_file = Company.objects.get(ticker_name=stock)
    stock_file = stock_file.data
    # Formatting data using find replace and regular expressions(Regex).
    stock_file = stock_file.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")
    stock_file = re.sub("(([^,]*,){5}[^,]*),\s*","\\1\n",stock_file)
    file_name = "/home/philip/PycharmProjects/stockmarket/static/stock_data/data_file.txt"
    file = open(file_name, "w")
    file.write(stock_file)
    file.close()
    date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=",", unpack=True, converters={ 0: date_converter })
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)
    ax1.plot(date, openp)
    ax1.plot(date, highp)
    ax1.plot(date, lowp)
    ax1.plot(date, closep)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(90)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=.10, bottom=.22, right=.93, top=.95)
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
    plt.suptitle(stock+': Stock Price')


    matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan(20122015, 20122015, facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5)   


    plt.show()
    plt.savefig("/home/philip/PycharmProjects/stockmarket/static/graph.svg")
```

Please excuse the messy nature of the code I am trying to fix this error and it is therefore being pulled apart. The line separated from the others is the line I've added to try and add a vertical span.

However when I run this code it gives this error...

```
ValueError at /stocks/

DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date.  This usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, eg with ax.xaxis_date()
```

When I try changing the code to...

```
matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan(ax1.xaxis_date(20122015), ax1.xaxis_date(20122015), facecolor='0.5', alpha=0.5)
```

Another error occurs...

```
TypeError at /stocks/

tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'int'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error.

Many Thanks.

Comment: It's going to be hard to provided a concrete answer with out an example that we can run. Your example code should generate the small (~10 lines) of data required to demonstrate the problem. In general though, you should be working `datetime` objects, not strings (`"2012-05-24"`) or unparseable integers (`20122015` -- python just thinks this is a big number)

Comment: Try replacing the line you've isolated with `ax1.xaxis_date()`. Just that - as suggested in the error message - no parameters or anything.  That just tells the x axis it's plotting dates, not numbers.